# fit element content of a div

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` which has alot of `ul` inside.. I want to fit them perfectly.. same height, width, padding andd etc. no matter how many `ul` I put inside a div.. if there is only two `ul`, I want them to fit perfectly if I add another one I want it to fit perfectly too. is it possible? not really good when it comes to designing..

here's a fiddle for you to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/SUBH3/104/

thanks in advance.

Comment: fit in horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal is it possible to do both...?

Comment: You can try like this - http://jsfiddle.net/SUBH3/109/

Answer (score 0):

Use `dl dt` to fit them. I can't open jsfiddle.net now, see if it is you want:

```
<style>
#wrap{
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}

dl{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;

}

dd{
    float: left;
}
</style>
<div id = "wrap">
    <dl>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent1</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent3</li>
                <li>SampleContent4</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
                <li>SampleContent2</li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this.

```
#wrap{
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}

ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

li {clear:both}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SUBH3/107/)